# Unable to use br tag html with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am working with html and javascript,I have "textarea" and i am inserting data into database after press "Enter key",But i am facing two problems

1. Right not unable to save data like "Lorem
   Ipsum" (
    tag not working)
2. Unable to clear "textarea",Right now textarea is clear but "cursor" is showing instead of placeholder (like before enter text),

Here is my html code

```
<textarea placeholder="Write a comment1…" id="txt'.$FeedId.'" data-txt='.$FeedId.' onkeypress="Addcomment1(this);"></textarea>
```

Here is my script,Where i am wrong ?

```
<script>
function Addcomment1(e) {
    var key = window.event.keyCode;
    var keys = window.event.shiftKey;
     if (key == 13 && keys == false) {
        var txt_id = e.dataset.txt;
        var textareavalue = $('#txt'+txt_id).val();
        $('#txt'+pid).val('');
        ...
    }       
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For your **second** problem, what you need to do is to [remove the focus (blur)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/blur).
Simply add this into your code after clearing your textarea:

```
$('#txt'+txt_id).val(''); //clearing the textarea
$('#txt'+txt_id).blur();  //removing the cursor and show placeholder
```

For the **first** problem, if you mean **newline** (pressing enter key) instead of **<br>** (inputting this text drectly in the textarea):

Since you seem to be using PHP, you can use the [**nl2br()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) function to make newlines show in HTML:

```
<?php
$text = nl2br($_POST["TEXTAREA_NAME_PUT_HERE"]);
?>
```

If you want to do this in client-side with JavaScript, you can use this instead:

```
var textareavalue = $('#txt'+txt_id).val().replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br>');
```

Overall, in JavaScript:

```
var textareavalue = $('#txt'+txt_id).val().replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br>');
...//save textareavalue in your own way
$('#txt'+txt_id).val('');
$('#txt'+txt_id).blur();
```

Comment: i want whenever user enter any text with br tag then that text should save with br tag ( means shift+enter key) ...for example 
"Lorem

Ipsum"

Comment: @Rajni Do you mean **newline** instead of **<br>**?

Comment: let me explain , for example i insert 
"Lorem
Ipsum" then this comment should save as it is(Lorem in first line and ipsum in second). But right now its not going to new line , right now displaying "Lorem Ipsum" (wihtout new line )

Comment: Yes, I understand. But what you probably want is the user to press the **enter key** instead of input the text **<br>** directly right?

Comment: If that's what you mean, I've updated the answer.

Comment: i want if user want to write something in new line then he can do with "shift+enter" key and if he want to save "comment" then he can do with just "enter" key , hope you understand my point

Comment: I got it, you can try the updated answer and see if it works :)

Comment: not working , means whenever i use "var textareavalue = $('#txt'+txt_id).val().replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br>') "

And i press "Enter" key then it is going to new line instead of "save" comment

Comment: Shift+Enter key to next line or Enter to next line. This begins to confuse me.

Comment: Let me explain 
"shit+enter means go to new line" And "Enter key" means save comment (by javascript")
Simple